# How can I make a function with two parameters to find if a node exists?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, nested-lists

I don't know if there is a method like: object or a map to check in nested objects.

The problem I have is that I have objects inside other objects. :/

I think the deeper the code should go would be:
node.children[1].children[0].children[0].children[0].name;

But I haven't been able to create a function to be recursive in that way.

```
    const rootNode = {
        name: "node1",
        children: [
            {
                name: "node2",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "node3",
                        tag: 251,
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "node4",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'node5',
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: "node7",
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: 'node8',
                                        children: [
                                            {
                                                name: "node6"
                                            },
                                        ],
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
    
    // YOU CAN MODIFY THIS PART ONLY
    /**
     * Search a node by name inside a node
     * @param node Any node to start the search in
     * @param nodeName The name to search
     * @returns undefined when no node is found or the founded node
     */
    const searchInNodeByName = (node, nodeName) => {
    
    
    }
    // HERE ENDS WHAT YOU CAN MODIFY
    
    const valueIsRecord = (value) => value !== null
        && typeof value === 'object'
        && !Array.isArray(value)
    
    const node6 = searchInNodeByName(rootNode, 'node6')
    
    if (
        node6 === undefined
        || !valueIsRecord(node6)
        || node6.name !== 'node6'
    ) {
        throw new Error('node6 should be found')
    }
    
    const node10 = searchInNodeByName(rootNode, 'node10')
    
    if (node10 !== undefined) {
        throw new Error('node10 should not be found')
    }
    
    const node3 = searchInNodeByName(rootNode, 'node3')
    
    if (
        node3 === undefined
        || !valueIsRecord(node3)
        || node3.name !== 'node3'
        || node3.tag !== 251
    ) {
        throw new Error('node3 should be found')
    }
    
    console.log('IF YOU SEE THIS ON YOUR CONSOLE, YOU ARE DONE!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const searchInNodeByName = (node, nodeName) => {
  if (node['name'] == nodeName) {
    return node;
  }
  else if (node['children'] != undefined) {
    for (let i = 0; i < node['children'].length; i++) {
      var checkChild = searchInNodeByName(node['children'][i], nodeName);
      if (checkChild !== undefined) {
        return checkChild;
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

This function will check the first node given, and return the node if the name equals the nodeName param. Otherwise, if there are children in that node, it will iterate through all children, and perform a recursive function to reach all nodes within the node param, prioritizing the node object.

Comment: I still receive this message: scriptTest.js:72 Uncaught Error: node6 should be found
    at scriptTest.js:72

Comment: I don't know if I am missing something from the tests.

Comment: @JoséAntonioMendozaChávez. You are receiving that error message because valueIsRecord only returns true if the value param is an object. The function in this answer was changed so instead of returning true/false, it will return the node/undefined depending on if the nodeName was found. I assume that's what you expected in the first place. Try that instead.